# How to wrap nvidia-smi calls to NVML?

Tags: c, linux, gpu, nvidia, ld-preload

I am trying to intercept the calls that nvidia-smi CLI makes to NVML in order to add some custom code (like for instance printing "I am here" every time nvidia-smi is called).

I am using ubuntu 20.04, with:

- NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01
- Driver Version: 515.65.01
- CUDA Version: 11.7

I have tried to override Nvidia NVML function calls using dlsym and LD_PRELOAD i.e.

```
nvmlReturn_t nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo_v2(nvmlDevice_t device, nvmlMemory_v2_t *memory){
    void* handle = dlopen("libnvidia-ml.so", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    nvmlReturn_t (*fn) (nvmlDevice_t, nvmlMemory_v2_t *) = (nvmlReturn_t (*) (nvmlDevice_t, nvmlMemory_v2_t *))dlsym(handle, "nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo_v2");
    nvmlReturn_t current_return = fn(device, memory);
    printf("i am here");
    return current_return;
}
```

I have compiled the code above with gcc as follows:

```bash
gcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -shared -fPIC -o mylib.so mylib.c -ldl -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lnvidia-ml
```

Finally, I have tried to execute the nvidia-smi command with LD_PRELOAD in order to load my code:

```bash
LD_PRELOAD=./mylib.so nvidia-smi
```

Nevertheless, I was unable to intercept any nvidia-smi calls of NVML, since the output `"I am here"` is never printed to screen.

I also have tried to wrap other functions but it seems that my code is never executed when invoking `nvidia-smi`. However, I have tried to `#include <nvml.h>` in a small project and I saw that in this case using LD_PRELOAD the functions calls are intercepted successfully.

Why does nvidia-smi seem not to be affected by the preload?
Am I wrapping the wrong functions or my library is not built/loaded correctly? Is there any other way to achieve this?